# Magento site showing raw php

Tags: php, magento

Heres the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ38i.png

I recently just moved a magento site to a new server and I'm now getting this. Everything else is working fine, but certain parts are not rendering. Does anyone have any idea what causes this?

FYIs: GD library and MCrypt are install. There are also no messages in system.log and error.log or in apaches logs

Comment: Looks like a possible problem with Short Tag configuration on your server

Comment: Could you provide some code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i didn't realize i was using PHP 5.3. I shouldn't have assumed it was 5.4. So Hobo Sapiens nailed it on the head.

I needed to enable shortcode.